# Ansible ios_command module is failing

Tags: ansible, cisco-ios

I am trying to to use the Ansible ios_command module in order to retrieve the router's version.

This is the playbook that I am running:

```
---
- name: POC playbook
  hosts: testlab
  gather_facts: no
  gather_subset: no
  tasks:
    - name: Show router version
      ios_command:
        commands: "show version"
```

Where the host, user, password and connection are defined in the hosts file:

```
[testlab]
<host>

[testlab]
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_ssh_user=<user>
ansible_ssh_pass=<password>
```

When I run the above playbook the following error occurs:

```
fatal: [host]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "failed to transfer file to \"` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1490199866.45-395283935741 `\" ) && sleep 0'\"/ios_command.py:\n\nAdministratively disabled.\n"}
```

I can ssh into the router with the designated user, run the "show version" command and get the expected output. So I don't believe it is a permission issue. I am not sure what the the issue might be so any help would be appreciated.

Below you can find the debug output

```
[root@tully ansible]# ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 ansible-playbook poc.yml | more

PLAY [POC playbook] ************************************************************
  3448 1490196133.51064: Loading StrategyModule 'linear' from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/strategy/linear.py
  3448 1490196133.51466: getting the remaining hosts for this loop
  3448 1490196133.51484: done getting the remaining hosts for this loop
  3448 1490196133.51503: building list of next tasks for hosts
  3448 1490196133.51512: getting the next task for host <host>
  3448 1490196133.51524: done getting next task for host <host>
  3448 1490196133.51535:  ^ task is: TASK: meta (flush_handlers)
  3448 1490196133.51543:  ^ state is: HOST STATE: block=1, task=1, rescue=0, always=0, role=None, run_state=ITERATING_TASKS, fail_state=FAILED_NONE, pending_setup=False, tasks child state? (None), rescue child state? (None), always child
 state? (None), did rescue? False, did start at task? False
  3448 1490196133.51550: done building task lists
  3448 1490196133.51555: counting tasks in each state of execution
  3448 1490196133.51562: done counting tasks in each state of execution:
        num_setups: 0
        num_tasks: 1
        num_rescue: 0
        num_always: 0
  3448 1490196133.51567: advancing hosts in ITERATING_TASKS
  3448 1490196133.51572: starting to advance hosts
  3448 1490196133.51581: getting the next task for host <host>
  3448 1490196133.51591: done getting next task for host <host>
  3448 1490196133.51599:  ^ task is: TASK: meta (flush_handlers)
  3448 1490196133.51607:  ^ state is: HOST STATE: block=1, task=1, rescue=0, always=0, role=None, run_state=ITERATING_TASKS, fail_state=FAILED_NONE, pending_setup=False, tasks child state? (None), rescue child state? (None), always child
 state? (None), did rescue? False, did start at task? False
  3448 1490196133.51614: done advancing hosts to next task
  3448 1490196133.52318: done queuing things up, now waiting for results queue to drain
  3448 1490196133.52330: results queue empty
  3448 1490196133.52337: checking for any_errors_fatal
  3448 1490196133.52342: done checking for any_errors_fatal
  3448 1490196133.52346: checking for max_fail_percentage
  3448 1490196133.52351: done checking for max_fail_percentage
  3448 1490196133.52356: checking to see if all hosts have failed and the running result is not ok
  3448 1490196133.52362: done checking to see if all hosts have failed

   [WARNING]: scp transfer mechanism failed on [<host>]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information
  3448 1490196133.52366: getting the remaining hosts for this loop
  3448 1490196133.52376: done getting the remaining hosts for this loop
  3448 1490196133.52394: building list of next tasks for hosts
  3448 1490196133.52401: getting the next task for host <host>
  3448 1490196133.52411: done getting next task for host <host>
  3448 1490196133.52419:  ^ task is: TASK: Show router version
  3448 1490196133.52426:  ^ state is: HOST STATE: block=2, task=1, rescue=0, always=0, role=None, run_state=ITERATING_TASKS, fail_state=FAILED_NONE, pending_setup=False, tasks child state? (None), rescue child state? (None), always child
 state? (None), did rescue? False, did start at task? False
  3448 1490196133.52431: done building task lists
  3448 1490196133.52436: counting tasks in each state of execution
  3448 1490196133.52442: done counting tasks in each state of execution:
        num_setups: 0
        num_tasks: 1
        num_rescue: 0
        num_always: 0
  3448 1490196133.52447: advancing hosts in ITERATING_TASKS
  3448 1490196133.52451: starting to advance hosts
  3448 1490196133.52456: getting the next task for host <host>
  3448 1490196133.52466: done getting next task for host <host>
  3448 1490196133.52475:  ^ task is: TASK: Show router version
  3448 1490196133.52483:  ^ state is: HOST STATE: block=2, task=1, rescue=0, always=0, role=None, run_state=ITERATING_TASKS, fail_state=FAILED_NONE, pending_setup=False, tasks child state? (None), rescue child state? (None), always child
 state? (None), did rescue? False, did start at task? False
  3448 1490196133.52488: done advancing hosts to next task
  3448 1490196133.52501: getting variables
  3448 1490196133.52507: in VariableManager get_vars()
  3448 1490196133.52567: done with get_vars()
  3448 1490196133.52592: done getting variables
  3448 1490196133.52602: sending task start callback, copying the task so we can template it temporarily
  3448 1490196133.52608: done copying, going to template now
  3448 1490196133.52614: done templating
  3448 1490196133.52619: here goes the callback...

TASK [Show router version] *****************************************************
  3448 1490196133.52636: sending task start callback
  3448 1490196133.52643: entering _queue_task() for <host>/ios_command
  3448 1490196133.52649: Creating lock for ios_command
  3448 1490196133.52899: worker is 1 (out of 1 available)
  3448 1490196133.52947: exiting _queue_task() for <host>/ios_command
  3448 1490196133.53031: done queuing things up, now waiting for results queue to drain
  3448 1490196133.53040: waiting for pending results...
  3794 1490196133.53535: running TaskExecutor() for <host>/TASK: Show router version
  3794 1490196133.53614: in run()
  3794 1490196133.53681: calling self._execute()
  3794 1490196133.54559: Loading Connection 'ssh' from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/ssh.py
  3794 1490196133.54837: Loading ShellModule 'csh' from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/shell/csh.py
  3794 1490196133.54905: Loading ShellModule 'fish' from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/shell/fish.py
  3794 1490196133.54994: Loading ShellModule 'powershell' from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/shell/powershell.py
  3794 1490196133.55026: Loading ShellModule 'sh' from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/shell/sh.py
  3794 1490196133.55078: Loading ShellModule 'sh' from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/shell/sh.py (found_in_cache=True, class_only=False)
  3794 1490196133.55101: in VariableManager get_vars()
  3794 1490196133.55166: done with get_vars()
  3794 1490196133.55218: Loading ActionModule 'normal' from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/action/normal.py
  3794 1490196133.55232: starting attempt loop
  3794 1490196133.55239: running the handler
  3794 1490196133.55307: ANSIBALLZ: Using lock for ios_command
  3794 1490196133.55315: ANSIBALLZ: Acquiring lock
  3794 1490196133.55324: ANSIBALLZ: Lock acquired: 34872464
  3794 1490196133.55332: ANSIBALLZ: Creating module
  3794 1490196133.90135: ANSIBALLZ: Writing module
  3794 1490196133.90178: ANSIBALLZ: Renaming module
  3794 1490196133.90195: ANSIBALLZ: Done creating module
  3794 1490196133.90296: _low_level_execute_command(): starting
  3794 1490196133.90307: _low_level_execute_command(): executing: /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1490196133.9-74490097367509 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1490196133.9-74490097367509="` echo ~/.ansible/tmp
/ansible-tmp-1490196133.9-74490097367509 `" ) && sleep 0'
  3794 1490196134.17414: stdout chunk (state=2):
>>>

*******************************************************************
* This system is for the use of authorized users only.            *
* Individuals using this computer system without authority, or in *
* excess of their authority, are subject to having all of their   *
* activities on this system monitored and recorded by system      *
* personnel.                                                      *
*                                                                 *
* In the course of monitoring individuals improperly using this   *
* system, or in the course of system maintenance, the activities  *
* of authorized users may also be monitored.                      *
*                                                                 *
* Anyone using this system expressly consents to such monitoring  *
* and is advised that if such monitoring reveals possible         *
* evidence of criminal activity, system personnel may provide the *
* evidence of such monitoring to law enforcement officials.       *
*******************************************************************

<<<
  3794 1490196134.18231: stdout chunk (state=3):
>>>
Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1490196133.9-74490097367509 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1490196133.9-74490097367509="` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1490196133.9-7449009736
7509 `" ) && sleep 0'"<<<
  3794 1490196134.48451: stdout chunk (state=3):
>>><<<
  3794 1490196134.48464: stderr chunk (state=3):
>>><<<
  3794 1490196134.48504: _low_level_execute_command() done: rc=0, stdout=

*******************************************************************
* This system is for the use of authorized users only.            *
* Individuals using this computer system without authority, or in *
* excess of their authority, are subject to having all of their   *
* activities on this system monitored and recorded by system      *
* personnel.                                                      *
*                                                                 *
* In the course of monitoring individuals improperly using this   *
* system, or in the course of system maintenance, the activities  *
* of authorized users may also be monitored.                      *
*                                                                 *
* Anyone using this system expressly consents to such monitoring  *
* and is advised that if such monitoring reveals possible         *
* evidence of criminal activity, system personnel may provide the *
* evidence of such monitoring to law enforcement officials.       *
*******************************************************************


Line has invalid autocommand "/bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1490196133.9-74490097367509 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1490196133.9-74490097367509="` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1490196133.9-7449009736
7509 `" ) && sleep 0'", stderr=
  3794 1490196134.48536: transferring module to remote "` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1490196133.9-74490097367509 `" ) && sleep 0'"/ios_command.py
  3794 1490196134.49556: Sending initial data
  3794 1490196134.49570: Sent initial data (121 bytes)
  3794 1490196135.05458: stderr chunk (state=3):
>>>Connection closed
<<<
  3794 1490196135.05486: stdout chunk (state=3):
>>><<<
  3794 1490196135.05494: stderr chunk (state=3):
>>><<<
  3794 1490196135.05695:
  3794 1490196135.05701: Connection closed
  3794 1490196135.31698: stderr chunk (state=2):
>>>Administratively disabled.
<<<
  3794 1490196135.31742: stdout chunk (state=3):
>>><<<
  3794 1490196135.31809:
  3794 1490196135.31816: Administratively disabled.
  3794 1490196135.31884: done running TaskExecutor() for <host>/TASK: Show router version
  3794 1490196135.31897: sending task result
  3794 1490196135.31975: done sending task result
  3794 1490196135.31984: WORKER PROCESS EXITING
  3448 1490196135.32117: in VariableManager get_vars()
  3448 1490196135.32202: done with get_vars()
  3448 1490196135.32224: marking <host> as failed
  3448 1490196135.32237: marking host <host> failed, current state: HOST STATE: block=2, task=1, rescue=0, always=0, role=None, run_state=ITERATING_TASKS, fail_state=FAILED_NONE, pending_setup=False, tasks chil
d state? (None), rescue child state? (None), always child state? (None), did rescue? False, did start at task? False
  3448 1490196135.32247: ^ failed state is now: HOST STATE: block=2, task=1, rescue=0, always=0, role=None, run_state=ITERATING_COMPLETE, fail_state=FAILED_TASKS, pending_setup=False, tasks child state? (None), rescue child state? (None)
, always child state? (None), did rescue? False, did start at task? False
  3448 1490196135.32256: getting the next task for host <host>
  3448 1490196135.32263: host <host> is done iterating, returning
fatal: [<host>]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "failed to transfer file to \"` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1490196133.9-74490097367509 `\" ) && sleep 0'\"/ios_command.py:\n\nAdministratively disabled.\
n"}
  3448 1490196135.32308: no more pending results, returning what we have
  3448 1490196135.32316: results queue empty
  3448 1490196135.32322: checking for any_errors_fatal
  3448 1490196135.32329: done checking for any_errors_fatal
  3448 1490196135.32334: checking for max_fail_percentage
  3448 1490196135.32339: done checking for max_fail_percentage
  3448 1490196135.32344: checking to see if all hosts have failed and the running result is not ok
  3448 1490196135.32349: done checking to see if all hosts have failed
  3448 1490196135.32353: getting the remaining hosts for this loop
  3448 1490196135.32362: done getting the remaining hosts for this loop
  3448 1490196135.32401: building list of next tasks for hosts
  3448 1490196135.32409: getting the next task for host <host>
  3448 1490196135.32416: host <host> is done iterating, returning
  3448 1490196135.32421: done building task lists
  3448 1490196135.32426: counting tasks in each state of execution
  3448 1490196135.32431: done counting tasks in each state of execution:
        num_setups: 0
        num_tasks: 0
        num_rescue: 0
        num_always: 0
  3448 1490196135.32436: all hosts are done, so returning None's for all hosts
  3448 1490196135.32441: done queuing things up, now waiting for results queue to drain
  3448 1490196135.32447: results queue empty
  3448 1490196135.32452: checking for any_errors_fatal
  3448 1490196135.32457: done checking for any_errors_fatal
  3448 1490196135.32461: checking for max_fail_percentage
  3448 1490196135.32466: done checking for max_fail_percentage
  3448 1490196135.32470: checking to see if all hosts have failed and the running result is not ok
  3448 1490196135.32478: done checking to see if all hosts have failed
  3448 1490196135.32488: getting the next task for host <host>
  3448 1490196135.32495: host <host> is done iterating, returning
  3448 1490196135.32502: running handlers
        to retry, use: --limit @/etc/ansible/poc.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
<host> : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Comment: You should use `local` connection and `provider` parameter to connect to routers. See module's documentation and related articles ([example](https://www.netnea.com/cms/2016/10/16/using-ansible-to-fetch-information-from-ios-devices/)) on the Internet.

Comment: That did it! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from the comments:

> You should use `local` connection and `provider` parameter to connect to routers. See module's documentation and related articles ([example](https://www.netnea.com/cms/2016/10/16/using-ansible-to-fetch-information-from-ios-devices/)) on the Internet